# how to obtain simplified Stanford Bunny model

Tags: graphics, resources, models, simplification

Some will object that this is not a programming question. I'm willing to defend its relevance to SO, or to take the question elsewhere, if someone has a good suggestion for a better place to get this sort of help.

The classic [Stanford Bunny model](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/3Dscanrep.html#bunny) has almost 70,000 polygons. I'm looking for a simplified version, on the order of 4,000 polygons. (This is for an open-source screen saver I'm working on.) Searching the web, I find that many people have simplified the model for various research projects. But I haven't found a downloadable, simplified model of the complexity I want.

The closest I've found is the [Scanview](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/software/scanview/) program, which comes with a 16,000-poly simplification of the model. However, it's provided in the binary SVM (ScanView Model?) format, for which I don't find ready information, and indeed the ScanView web page suggests that it may be encrypted and please don't hack it. :-)

I've searched in a few of the major online 3D model download sites, and haven't found the bunny at all there. This surprises me, given the [popularity of the bunny](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~turk/bunny/bunny.html), and the fact that permission is granted to redistribute it freely.

If there is not a readily-available simplified model to download, what is the easiest way for me to simplify it myself? Use a program like [meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)?

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Data/Meshes/bunny.obj

> ```
> # OBJ file format with ext .obj
> # vertex count = 2503
> # face count = 4968
> ```

Comment: FYI to future readers... this download lacks surface normals, but it was easy to add normals by loading the file in MeshLab and saving it again in .obj format.

Comment: The link is broken. Can you please put the file on Google Drive and share the link?